# Passing parameters though java file in batch

Tags: java, batch-file, osgi

I'm trying to run a console of a java file and send some commands to that console, **without** using an external file.

e.g.

`java -jar "D:AndroidProjects\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar" -console < ss.txt`

Someone know how to pass parameters to the java file console?

http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2273/41496357.png

Edited:
I do not think I explained myself well enough.`org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar` is not develop by me.

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase your question, you want to issue some OSGi console commands automatically at startup, right? Probably your main goal is to specify the URLs of bundles you want to load?

Everything you do at the console can also be done programmatically. You should create a jar with an activator that can perform the startup actions you wish.

Alternatively, if there are configurations you need before any other bundles are loaded, then it's not hard to write your own main() that does a few tasks then launches the framework bundle.

An Eclipse-specific alternative is to create a config.ini file that the Equinox kernel will read. The config.ini can list all of your startup bundles.

An even friendlier option, in my opinion, is the Apache Karaf container. It has a really nice web console for manually adding bundles, and a few convenient ways to automatically add bundles (startup.properties, the deploy folder, and Karaf features.xml)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you give me some reference where show an example of this type of comunication?

Answer (score 0):

the main method of your application can read them from the array args[]